# Como criar e remover alias no GIT

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber os comandos para se criar uma alias, fiquei sabendo que posso encurtar meus comandos e tornar mais rápido e produtivo, mais ainda não sei como fazer isto. Alguém sabe os comandos de criar e remover?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podes adicionar os mesmos ao teu `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    st = status
    ci = commit -v
```

Ou podes fazer uso do comando `alias` do git config:

```
$ git config --global alias.st status 
$ git config --global alias.ci 'commit -v'
```

Mais informações podem ser vistas na [documentação](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

---

<sup>Créditos da resposta para o @Diego Dias no SOEN [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553799/352449).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Vou supor que você trabalha em ambiente Linux ou OSX.

Esses aliases você coloca no seu arquivo `~/.bashrc` (no caso do Linux) ou no arquivo `~/.bash_profile` (no caso do OSX). Edite-os no Vim (não precisa de `sudo`) e coloque alguns aliases do tipo:

```
alias gs='git status;'
alias gc='git commit $1;'
alias gca='git commit -am $1;'
alias gcap='git commit -am $1; git push;'
```

(só um detalhe: use `=` e não `=` com espaços em volta, pois esse é um operador de comparação)

Enfim, esses são alguns dos comandos que configuro para o meu ambiente. Você pode criar os comandos que quiser para o seu caso.

Ah! Não se esqueça de dar um `source ~/.bashtrc` (ou `source ~/.bash_profile` no caso do OSX) para carregar os comandos depois que você inseri-los. Entretanto, sempre que você reiniciar o sistema, os comandos já estarão disponíveis.